# Directory.EnumerateDirectories() hang on some network folders

Tags: c#, windows-server

I have this simple C# code:

```
foreach (string s in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(root))
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

`root` is a string (UNC) to a network share (Windows) containing 10520 files and **no subfolders**. I would expect `Directory.EnumerateDirectories(root)` to return an empty collection, but it hangs. I have waited several minutes.

The DOS command "dir" work as expected and even "Properties" in Windows Explorer completes the task in 5 seconds reporting "10 520 Files, 0 Folders"

My guess is that there is some limit either on the file server or on my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is most likely with .net itself. Sometimes (if not always) it's slower than native Windows API.

Command Line and Explorer are working with WinAPI that is why they are so fast.

Fortunately there is a possibility to invoke WinAPI via C# using P/Invoke.

There are a lot of examples, like [this](http://tom-shelton.net/index.php/category/net/c/pinvoke-c-net/).

Comment: Isn't it strange that .Net is considerably slower than WinAPI? I mean, I've been around and coded C and C++ with WinAPI since the Gulf War, and if I was asked to port or wrap a FindFirstFile/FindNextFile, I would have used WinAPI and returned an IEnumerable just as in the URL ieaglle provided. Some .Net designer obviously added some safety code that made it slow.

I also have to mention that the slow/hang scenario is not for every directory on the server. Probably just the big ones.

Comment: there's always a price for benefits

Comment: Accepting the answer although I don't like it ;-) Using P/Invoke to fix the framework doesn't sound good to me. Anyway... Thanks!